# Logical differences between very similar terms in beginner javascript

Tags: javascript, logic

What is the difference between these two terms:

```
 if(counter % 4 != 0) 
 if(counter % 4 == !0)
```

I can't see any logical difference, yet my computer does (and I am 100% sure my computer is more logical than I).

All insight appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `!` (not) operator in JavaScript performs type coercion - it tries to convert the value to a Boolean (true or false) value. 0 in JavaScript is *falsy*, so !0 is the opposite of false, ie true.

So your first `if` remains the same:

```
if(counter % 4 != 0)
```

but the second is actually

```
 if(counter % 4 == true)
```

which is definitely not the same.

Edit:

JavaScript also does type coercion when using the non-strict `!=` and `==` operators (vs the strict `!==` and `===`) so in this case if `counter % 4` becomes 1, it will evaluate to `true` since `1` is a truthy value.

Here's a list of falsy values in JavaScript: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: Note that the type-coercion on `== true` will be `ToNumber()` ([6-7 of 11.9.3](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)), resulting in `== 1` rather than testing the *truthiness* of `counter % 4`.

Comment: Nicely explained and helpful additional insight. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

It might make more sense if you try to *read* your code as text:

- Is `counter % 4` the same as `not 0`?

`not 0`, or `!0`, gives `true` in Javascript, so it'd be:

- Is `counter % 4` the same as `true`?

The result of the statement depends on the value of `counter`. See Google Chrome's Javascript console for clarification:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

!0 is 1 so your conditional's look like this:

```
if(counter % 4 != 0)   
if(counter % 4 == 1)
```

Comment: Wrong.  alert(!0 + 2);  ==>3.  if (3 == !0) { alert('yes');}  ==> nothing.  if (3) { alert('yes');}  ==> 'yes'.

Comment: `!0 + 2` ⇒ 3, but only because `true + 2` ⇒ 3.

Comment: ...so if 3 is true and !0 is true, then 3 == !0 should be true, but it isn't.

Comment: And that explains why it is [usually] better to use `===` and `!==` when doing comparisons.

Comment: I'm just going to bring the `===` operator in here for clarity. `alert((!0) === 1)` ⇒ `false`, but `alert((!0) === true)` ⇒ `true`.

Comment: @7stud: `3` is *truthy*, not `true`. The same way `''` and `0` are falsy.